# why we include path before using pip command

Tags: path

When ever we try to run the command `pip intall nltk` or `pip install numpy` we get error that pip is not recognized as internal or external command then we add pip to the path. I want to know that what is path and why we add link in path. Any one help please.

Comment: Cross-site answer maybe useful or related: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linux Information Project](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html):

> PATH is an environmental variable in Linux and other Unix-like operating systems that tells the shell which directories to search for executable files (i.e., ready-to-run programs) in response to commands issued by a user. It increases both the convenience and the safety of such operating systems and is widely considered to be the single most important environmental variable.

So basically it's a list of directories in which the shell looks to find commands.

Let's say your `pip` is installed at `/usr/local/bin/pip`, and `/usr/local/bin/` is not in your `PATH` variable, the shell won't be able to find `pip`.

If you're using Python virtual environment, like `python3 -m venv my-venv`, you usually have to `source bin/activate` under my-venv, which adds all scripts under my-venv/bin to your `PATH` variable for the current shell. Then your shell will be able to find the virtual environment-specific scripts.

Since `PATH` is set by the login shell, when you close the current shell and open a new one, the variable gets reset. Then you have to call `source bin/activate` under my-venv again to get shell look into your virtual environment.